# What is this woody plant?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

I just dug up this tree (I think it is a tree), and I wanted to know if someone could help me identify it. Click for larger images.

[image]
[image]

This woody plant was growing in Illinois near some marshy land before it was dug up.  The specific location was:

http://www.dupageforest.com/Conservation/ForestPreserves/Hidden_Lake.html

I have been trying to use the following resource but cannot seem to identify the plant:

http://woodyplants.nres.uiuc.edu/

**FEATURES:**

- opposite branching
- simple leaves
- leave outline smooth
- young branches hairy

**DIFFERENTIAL:**

- Honeysuckle
- Dogwood

Comment: It's probably a shrub.  If you're lucky, you might get a flower or two this year, which will help a lot with identifying it.

Comment: Where was it growing before it was dug up? Have you observed it in previous years?

Comment: What area of the world do you live in?

Comment: Hope u didn't dig out a tree from a wilderness area :~~~~~~~~~~(

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-native bush honeysuckle, most likely [Amur honeysuckle](http://www.missouriplants.com/Whiteopp/Lonicera_maackii_page.html) (*Lonicera maackii*). It's a terrible, highly invasive weed across most of eastern North America. I'm sure the DuPage Forest Preserve District would be more than happy if you called them up and volunteered to help them remove more of it :) (but fyi, it's illegal to dig it or any other plants up from the preserve on your own without permission).